# Attiny45 resets when setting digitalOutput to low

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny

I currently try to program an Attiny45 with an Arduino UNO as ISP.

The Arduino is able to program the Attiny45.

However, when I try the blink example, it resets the Attiny, when setting digitalOutput to low
(on any pin)

To further confirm, that it resets only, when setting a pin to low, I wrote this sketch and let it run on the Attiny.

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delay(10000);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
}
```

The LED I connected to pin 3 waits 1 second, and then turns on, but when 1 second passed and it should stay off for 10 seconds, it resets and only waits 1 second.

I tried reburning the bootloader onto the Attiny, which had no effect.

Comment: Could you show the wiring diagram?

Comment: I follwed these [instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Program-an-ATtiny-with-Arduino/step2/Wire-the-circuit/)

Comment: Including the 220Ω resistor with the LED as in the last step?

Comment: My LED can handle 5V, so I used it without, but that cant be the issue

Comment: That would be a very special LED then, if it can handle 5V without a resistor.

Comment: "Can handle" and "Is designed to work with" are two *very* different things. Chances are it can't handle it, but it's not getting it. Instead it is causing massive power droop from over current making the BOD trigger in the ATTiny.

Comment: If it would be the BOD, then how come that the attiny only resets, when setting the pin to low?

Comment: Ok it the resistor actually fixed it, but still. Why only when setting it to low?

Comment: Because the wiring shown there has the LED connected between the IO pin and +5V, so the IO pin, when switched LOW, turns the LED on by acting as ground.

Comment: Ok, but there I connected the LED frome the IO as output to Groud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Including the 220Ω resistor with the LED as in the last step?

...

> My LED can handle 5V, so I used it without, but that cant be the issue

The one thing that "can't be the issue" is indeed the issue! Without a resistor the LED will attempt to conduct a lot of current which will damage both it and the output pin of the processor.

See [The care and feeding of LEDs](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Tutorial/LEDs.html). From that page:

> LEDs are not like normally electronic devices in that you can’t just apply a voltage to them and they work, they have to be fed the correct voltage and current to keep them happy.

And then:

> There are several web sites and schematics on the web that suggest you can attach an LED directly to an Arduino output pin with no current limiting resistor. They are wrong, and following them will damage your Arduino.

---

So, by not using a resistor, when the output pin goes LOW it attempts to "sink" current, in order to turn on the LED. Since you have no resistor, it sinks as much as the output drivers can handle, dropping the supply voltage inside the Attiny, which then goes below the brownout level, and resets itself.

Please, when following a circuit, don't just omit bits of it, and then post a question about why it doesn't work. At least follow the circuit exactly, and then when you have learned more about electronics, you can start experimenting.

Comment: Where am I supposed to ask if not on a forum ment for it?

Comment: I searched more than enough times, so I think me asking would be totally valid.

Comment: I didn't say to not ask *here*, I said to *follow the instructions* first. You said "I followed these instructions" but you didn't. You left out part of them (the resistor). Nor did you say that in your question. You might have said "I followed the instructions but omitted the resistor which I didn't think was important".

Comment: Ok, that made more sense, then sorry if I seemed a little aggressive, and thank you :)